What is a natural interpretation of the commutator of the conditional expectation operator?
Notation: We denote by $\mathbb E_{\mathcal F} X$ the conditional expectation of the random variable $X$ with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$.
Given two $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal G, \mathcal H$, it is in general not true that the iterated conditional expectation operators $\mathbb E_{\mathcal G} \mathbb E_{\mathcal H}$ and $\mathbb E_{\mathcal H} \mathbb E_{\mathcal G}$ are equal. An elementary example of these being different is given in zoli's answer to Is this chaining property of conditional expectation correct?.
This prompts the following soft question — what is a natural interpretation of the commutator $\mathbb E_{\mathcal G} \mathbb E_{\mathcal H} -\mathbb E_{\mathcal H} \mathbb E_{\mathcal G}$?
Remarks, and a more precise question:
The commutator vanishes when the two $\sigma$-algebras are independent, as well as when they are fully dependent, in the sense that one is a sub $\sigma$-algebra of the other.
In fact, in both cases we have $\mathbb E_{\mathcal G} \mathbb E_{\mathcal H} = \mathbb E_{\mathcal H} \mathbb E_{\mathcal G} = \mathbb E_{\mathcal G \cap \mathcal H}$.
Of course, if conditional on some auxiliary $\sigma$-algebra, we have that $\mathcal G$ and $\mathcal H$ are either conditionally independent or conditionally fully dependent, then we can conclude that the commutator vanishes as well.
Are these the only cases in which the commutator vanishes?
Note: By equality of the operators, we mean that $\mathbb E_{\mathcal G} \mathbb E_{\mathcal H} X = \mathbb E_{\mathcal H} \mathbb E_{\mathcal G} X$ almost surely, for all random variables $X$.

If $\Omega=[0,1)^3$, equipped with Lebesgue measure and $\mathcal G$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the first two coordinates; and $\mathcal H$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the second and third coordinates, the commutator vanishes. Is this what you meant by conditionally independent?

The conditional expectation is a projection on $L^2(X)$, and projections $P,Q$ commute if and only if $PQ$ is a projection also (on $R(P)\cap R(Q)$ in that case).

@AnthonyQuas Hmm, denoting by $\mathcal A$ the auxillary $\sigma$-algebra, I just mean that under the regular conditional probability $\text{Pr}(\cdot | \mathcal A)$, the $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal G$ and $\mathcal H$ are independent.

I think in your example, if you let $\mathcal A$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by only the second coordinate, this is exactly an instance of what i mentioned. Your $\mathcal G$ and $\mathcal H$ are conditionally independent given $\mathcal A$.

I think an easier to grasp example, while being effectively the same as your Lebesgue measure one is this - roll three standard dice. Let $G$ be the sum of the first two rolls, and $H$ the sum of the last two. Then $G$ and $H$ are not independent, but they are conditionally independent given $A$, the second roll alone.

And indeed in this case the commutator of $\mathcal G$ and $\mathcal H$ vanishes, because on the level of $\sigma$-algebras, they are conditionally independent given $\mathcal A$.

Although, your example would correspond actually to $G$ and $H$ being the actual displayed face values. Nevertheless, your conclusion still holds.

@NateRiver : What do you mean by "conditionally fully dependent"?

@Iosif Pinelis In this case, that $\mathcal G \subset \mathcal H$ modulo null sets as measured by $\text{Pr}(\cdot| \mathcal A)$.

The full statement i guess is this - assume for $\mathbb P$-almost all $\omega$, either $G \subset H$ modulo $\text{Pr}(\cdot | \mathcal A)(\omega)$-null sets (or vice versa), or $\mathcal G$ and $\mathcal H$ are independent under $\text{Pr}(\cdot | \mathcal A)(\omega)$. Then the commutator vanishes.

@NateRiver : Thank you for the clarifying response. You might want to include it into your post.

@IosifPinelis will do!

O. Kallenberg has shown [Theorem 5.1 in "Commutativity properties of conditional distributions and Palm measures", Commun. Stoch. Anal. 4 (2010) 21–34] that the two conditional expectation operators commute if and only if $\mathcal G$ and $\mathcal H$ are conditionally independent given $\mathcal G\cap\mathcal H$. He also observes that this happens if and only if $G\perp H$ on $(G\cap H)^\perp$, where $G$ and $H$ are the associated $L^2$ spaces.

Nice, this is exactly what I was looking for. Since the original question of the qualitative interpretation of the conditional expectation is still interesting, I’ll leave the question open. But thanks for your answer!
